# Householder's method not returning desired values

Tags: java, math, numerical-methods

I'm taking the numerical methods curse. As part of a homework, I was asked to implement the Householder's Method. In order to do it, I was supposed to look into Numerical Analysis by Burden and Faires. I already coded the method according with the steps explained in such book; however, I am not getting the desired result.
Here is the code:

```
public static double[][] householder(int n, double[][] matrix) {
double a, rsq, prod = 0, q = 0;
double[] v = new double[n];
double[] u = new double[n];
double[] z = new double[n];

//step 1
for(int k = 0; k < n - 2; k++) {

  //step 2
  for(int j = k + 1; j < n; j++)
    q += Math.pow(matrix[j][k], 2);

  //step 3
  if(matrix[k+1][k] == 0)
    a = -1 * (Math.sqrt(q));
  else
    a = -1 * (Math.sqrt(q) * matrix[k + 1][k] / Math.abs(matrix[k+1][k]));


  //step 4
  rsq = Math.pow(a, 2) - (a * matrix[k + 1][k]);

  //step 5
  v[k + 1] = matrix[k + 1][k] - a;
  for(int j = k + 2; j < n; j++)
    v[j] = matrix[j][k];

  //step 6
  for(int j = k; j < n; j++) {
    double temp = 0;
    for(int i = k + 1; i < n; i++)
      temp += matrix[j][i] * v[i];
    u[j] = (1 / rsq) * temp;
  }

  //step 7
  for(int i = k + 1; i < n; i++)
    prod += v[i] * u[i];

  //step 8
  for(int j = k; j < n; j++)
    z[j] = u[j] - ((prod / (2 * rsq)) * v[j]);

  //step 9
  for(int l = k + 1; l < n - 1; l++) {
    //step 10
    for(int j = l + 1; j < n; j++) {
      matrix[j][l] = matrix[j][l] - (v[l] * z[j]) - (v[j] * z[l]);
      matrix[l][j] = matrix[j][l];
    }
    //step 11
    matrix[l][l] = matrix[l][l] - 2 * (v[l] * z[l]);
  }

  //setp 12
  matrix[n - 1][n - 1] = matrix[n - 1][n - 1] - 2 * (v[n - 1] * z[n - 1]);

  //step 13
  for(int j = k + 2; j < n; j++)
    matrix[k][j] = matrix[j][k] = 0;

  //step 14
  matrix[k + 1][k] = matrix[k + 1][k] - (v[k + 1] * z[k]);
  matrix[k][k + 1] = matrix[k + 1][k];

}
//step 15
return matrix;
```

}

---

To test the method I used a matrix that's provided as an example in the book:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
double matrix[][] ={
  {4, 1, -2, 2},
  {1, 2, 0, 1},
  {-2, 0, 3, -2},
  {2, 1, -2, -1}
};
matrix = householder(matrix.length, matrix);
for (int i=0; i< matrix.length ; i++) {
  for (int j=0; j < matrix[0].length ; j++) {
    System.out.printf("%.4f", matrix[i][j]);
    System.out.print(" | ");
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

}

---

As I used the matrix provided in the book, the resulting values are supposed to be the same as the ones in the book, but they are not. I don't a clue of what I'm doing wrong so I'm hopping if anyone can help.

---

This is the algorithm:
[Householder's Method by Numerical Analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fEwi.jpg) 
These are the desired values: [Matrix with desired values after Householder's method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggSM3.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of small mistakes in the code:

- `q` is not set to 0 before the loop in Step 2.
- `v[k]` is not set to 0 in step 5.
- `prod` is not set to 0 before step 7.

The rest look fine. I did not test it though. Tell me if it works!